# Copy Paste entities from a project to another symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a projet that includes many entities and their controller and crud, etc

I want to reuse them in another projet. So I want to copy paste the files.

But I already have a problem at entity creation:
The cmd shows that `make: entity` creates the entity class and the repository class (and nothing else) .So I copy paste these two to the new projet but they are ignored:
When I try `make:migration`, I got No database changes were detected. When I try `make:entity` and type the name of the entity class (Taxe), I got _Cannot find the entity manager for class "App\Entity\Taxe" . and `make:controller` with Taxe as entity return _ Entity "Taxe" doesn't exist; .

So globally, how to create entity without the maker ? How can I reuse my entities/controllers/etc from another project pls?

Comment: Did you put these entities in the `src/Entity` folder? Have you updated the schema with the following commands? `php bin/console make:migration` and after `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` to run the migration.

Answer (score 1):

Globally, to reuse your controllers/entities, just copy/paste them in the right folder.

Entities : src/Entity
Controllers : src/Controller
Repositories: src/Repository

After that (if your database is created, else run `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`) , you can make `php bin/console make:migration` and `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` to apply changements.

> The cmd shows that make: entity creates the entity class and the repository class (and nothing else)

If you want to generate templates, you have to run `php bin/console make:controller`, name your controller and controller file + template will be generated (this implies that your project is a web app and not an api).